# Angular material $mdDialog.hide() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I am working with angular material. i am using the $mdDialog to create a pop up on my application. everything works fine except the $mdDialog.hide() is not working.

```
       $ctrl.footerModal = function () {
            $mdDialog.show({
                template: '<md-dialog aria-label="Privacy Policy">' +
                '<md-dialog-content>' +
                '<div class="md-dialog-content">' +
                '<h2>Privacy Policy</h2>' +
                '<p> sum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer ' +
                'took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, ' +
                'but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s ' +
                ' with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desk</p>' +
                '<p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</md-dialog-content>' +
                '<md-dialog-actions layout="row">' +
                '<span flex>' + '</span>' +
                '<md-button ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">' +
                'Ok' +
                '</md-button>' +
                '</md-dialog-actions>' +
                '</md-dialog>',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose: true
            });
            $ctrl.cancel = function () {
                $mdDialog.hide();
            };
        }
```

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Where you used `$mdDialog.hide()`?

Comment: i have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.hide`,

```
$scope.cancel = function() {
   $mdDialog.hide();
};
```

**EDIT:**

Your `$ctrl.cancel` function should be placed outside as Ramesh mentioned

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCHFaE?p=preview)**

Comment: He's also using this same

Comment: @RameshRajendran no he was using .cancel, now he has edited

Comment: That's y I have putting comment. Kindly update your answer for OP updated question. I remove my down vote

Comment: @RameshRajendran cant you check the demo i provided?

Answer (score 1):

Please write your code outside of `$ctrl.footerModal` function,

Your code should be

```
$ctrl.footerModal = function () {
            $mdDialog.show({
                template: '<md-dialog aria-label="Privacy Policy">' +
                '<md-dialog-content>' +
                '<div class="md-dialog-content">' +
                '<h2>Privacy Policy</h2>' +
                '<p> sum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer ' +
                'took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, ' +
                'but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s ' +
                ' with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desk</p>' +
                '<p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</md-dialog-content>' +
                '<md-dialog-actions layout="row">' +
                '<span flex>' + '</span>' +
                '<md-button ng-click="cancel()">' +
                'Ok' +
                '</md-button>' +
                '</md-dialog-actions>' +
                '</md-dialog>',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose: true
            });
         }

 $ctrl.cancel = function () {
             $mdDialog.hide();
         };
```